# Putting poison inside bamboo rods (s'chach)

Tags: sukkah, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, bugs, schach

It says in [Shulchan Aruch (OC Siman 629 Sif 3)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=175&hilite=) that one may cover a Sukkah with "chitzim" (arrows) that don't have a "beis kibbul." However, if they do have a "beis kibbul," then it's not valid for schach. "Beis kibbul" basically means some opening or cup that can be a receptacle, and can therefore be made tamei (impure). The Magen Avraham writes (ad loc., Sif-Katan 2) that "kanim" (rods) that have a "beis kibbul" are valid, since they weren't *made* to be "m'kabel". Seemingly this is similar to our bamboo sticks or the like that people use for schach. However, what about if one would put some sort of "chomer" (a poison or the like) used to kill bugs inside of the sticks? I'm not talking about a spray or something of the like – rather something that has to it mamoshos (substance) that sits in the sticks and helps to kill the bugs. Even though these kanim, like the M"A says, weren't *made* to be a beis kibbul, since l'maseh (practically) they are being used in such a way, does this invalidate it for being schach?

Comment: _Comments related to the use of jargon in questions have been moved to a dedicated [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5878/discussion-between-yehoshua-sethj-monica-cellio-and-double-aa)._

Comment: How would you translate חיצים? Arrows? Or just sticks? (I'm asking anybody, nobody in particular.)

Comment: Clearly as arrows, from context in the gemara (how to attach the arrowheads)